# How do you force a view controller to call preferredFocusView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tvos, focus-engine

So I have a view controller that has the following methods:

```
    var viewToFocus: UIView? = nil {
        didSet {
            if viewToFocus != nil {
                self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
                self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
        if viewToFocus != nil {
            let theView = viewToFocus
            viewToFocus = nil
            return theView
        } else {
            return super.preferredFocusedView;
        }
    }
```

So essentially I can force a focus update to the view I want by setting `viewToFocus` to a value, which works great in most cases. However, when removing a subview this doesn't seem to work properly and `preferredFocusedView` is never called.

In terms of my subview, it's an overlay that covers the screen (don't ask why I didn't use a modal, there were reasons for that) and has the parent view controller as a delegate. The parent view controller has the following methods:

```
// Delegate of 'OverlayView'. Called BEFORE it is added as a subview
func beforeOpeningOverlay() {
    focusedViewBeforeOverlay = UIScreen.mainScreen().focusedView
}

// Delegate of 'OverlayView'. Called after its close action is triggered.
func closedOverlay(overlay: OverlayView) {
    if focusedViewBeforeOverlay != nil {
        viewToFocus = focusedViewBeforeOverlay
        focusedViewBeforeOverlay = nil
    }
    overlay.delegate = nil
    overlay.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

For some reason when closedOverlay is called, and `focusedViewBeforeOverlay` has a valid non-nil view, it is never the next view focused on after the overlay is removed from the superview. Like I said `preferredFocusedView` is never called, and focus instead focuses on whatever the focus engine decides should be the next focus.

Anyone know why that might be the case? Does removing a subview not allow you to trigger a focus update?

**So the order, or at least expected order, should be:**

1. Something triggers `OverlayView` to be instantiated
2. `beforeOpeningOverlay()` is called, and the currently focused view is set to `focusedViewBeforeOverlay`. The overlay is then opened and captures focus
3. Something triggers the overlay view to close, calling `closedOverlay()`
4. `viewToFocus = focusedViewBeforeOverlay` line is called
5. A focus update should be called for the parent viewcontroller, calling its `preferredFocusedView`
6. `preferredFocusedView` should return `viewToFocus` which was set to `focusedViewBeforeOverlay` and revert focus back to the view that was focused before the overlay opens

The issue seems to be that step 5 and onwards aren't called

Comment: Have you tried calling calling `setNeedsFocusUpdate()` and `updateFocusIfNeeded()`?

Comment: Yeah, they're called when `viewToFocus` is set

Comment: Ah, my bad, I somehow missed that.  In my experience when I started trying to control the focus engine, I had to do it everywhere (even container view controllers, for example).  Have you looked at if any container view controllers are having their methods called and just not passing it along?

Comment: For example, I just looked back at my most recent tvOS project and I see that I had a subclass of UITabBarController for this very reason.  At the very minimum it can be handy to make such subclasses and throw in the relevant did/will update focus methods, override preferredFocusedView calling super, and just put breakpoints in to see what's actually happening.

Comment: preferredfocusedview  was deprecated in tvOS10 https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifocusenvironment/1616830-preferredfocusedview

Comment: Have a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837449/tvos-focus-not-moving-correctly?#answer-52251007

Answer (score 1):

As Roman commented, `referredFocusedView` was deprecated in tvOS 10. Now you have to define your `preferredFocusEnvironments`.

That in your case would be something like:

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    if let focusEnviroment = self.viewToFocus { return [focusEnviroment] }
    return super.preferredFocusEnvironments
}
```

You also need to call `self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()` for *updating* the focus.