# tvOS: Focus not moving correctly

Tags: focus, tvos

I have a UIView with two buttons on it. In the `MyView` class I have this code:

```
-(BOOL) canBecomeFocused {
    return YES;
}

-(NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments {
    return @[_editButton, _addButton];
}

-(IBAction) editTapped:(id) sender {
    BOOL editing = !tableViewController.editing;
    [_editButton setTitle:editing ? @"Done" : @"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _addButton.hidden = !editing;
    [tableViewController setEditing:editing animated:YES];
```

}

The basic idea is that the user can move the focus to the edit button, which can then make the Add button appear.

The problem started because every time I tapped the edit button, focus would shift to the table view. I would actually like it to move to the Add button. I also want it so that when editing it deactivated, the edit button keeps the focus. but again it's shifting down to the table view.

So I tried the above code. This works in that focus can move to the view and on to the button. But once it's there, I cannot get it to move anywhere else.

Everything I've read says just override `preferredFocusEnvironments` but so far I've not been able to get this to work. Focus keeps going to a button then refusing to move anywhere else.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is proving really difficult. Am trying now using a `UIFocusGuide` but it looks like the shift of focus from the buttons down to the table view is a system generated move and ignores my focus guide. Even though I have it sitting between them. Grrr. !

Answer (score 4):

If anybody is facing this issue, Just check if you are getting the following debug message printed in the console.

> WARNING: Calling updateFocusIfNeeded while a focus update is in progress. This call will be ignored.

I had the following code :

```
// MARK: - Focus Environment

var viewToBeFocused: UIView?

func updateFocus() {
    setNeedsFocusUpdate()
    updateFocusIfNeeded()
}

override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    if let viewToBeFocused = self.viewToBeFocused {
        self.viewToBeFocused = nil
        return [viewToBeFocused]
    }
    return super.preferredFocusEnvironments
}
```

I was calling the `updateFocus()` method multiple times while `viewToBeFocused` was either nil or some other view. Debugging the focus issues mainly between transition is really difficult. You should have patience.

> Important to note: This depends on your use case, but if you want to
>   update the focus right after a viewcontroller transition (backward
>   navigation), You might have to set the following in viewDidLoad:

```
restoresFocusAfterTransition = false // default is true
```

If this is true, the view controller will have the tendancy to focus the last focused view even if we force the focus update by calling `updateFocusIfNeeded()`. In this case , since a focus update is already in process, you will get the warning as mentioned before at the top of this answer.

## Debug focus issue

Use the following link to debug the focus issues: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus_interactions/debugging_focus_issues_in_your_app

Enable the focus debugger first under Edit scheme > Arguments passed on launch:

```
-UIFocusLoggingEnabled YES
```

[image]

This will log all the attempts made by the focus engine to update the focus. This is really helpful.

Comment: For me it was ensuring that I did not call "updateFocusIfNeeded()" in "viewDidAppear()" - probably because, as stated in the answer, the app was already in the middle of a focus change at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the preferredFocusEnviromnets with the following logic:

```
-(NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments {
    if (condition) {
        return @[_editButton];
    }
    else {
        return @[_addButton];
    }
}
```

After setting it, you can call

```
[_myView setNeedsFocusUpdate];
[_myView updateFocusIfNeeded];
```

The condition could be `BOOL condition = tableViewController.editing;` or sg like that.

If that now works, you can call it with a delay (0.1 sec or so).